# Replace a specific sub-string at specific position using LINQ

Tags: c#, string, linq, replace

I have a list of abbreviation and position, that i want to replace specific specific abbreviation not all the abbreviation.

```
public class Abbreviation
{
    public int Pos { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public string LongName { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Abbreviation> abbreviations = new List<Abbreviation>();
        abbreviations.Add(new Abbreviation() { Pos = 28, ShortName = "exp.", LongName = "expression" });
        abbreviations.Add(new Abbreviation() { Pos = 38, ShortName = "para.", LongName = "paragraph" });
        abbreviations.Add(new Abbreviation() { Pos = 51, ShortName = "ans.", LongName = "answer" });

        string test = "What is exp.? This is a test exp. in a para. contains ans. for a question";
        abbreviations.ForEach(x => ...); // Need a LINQ expression
        Console.WriteLine(test);
    }
}
```

How to do that in LINQ?

Comment: So `Pos` corresponds to the position in the string?  Meaning if `exp.` is not at position 30 it should be ignored (i.e not replaced)?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: Does your current code work?

Comment: Is the first "exp." position 8?

Comment: You should provide a clear list what you have tried, and a clear input, output. 
I would recommend expanding on your question, to ease people to understand the issue. Just fyi. The prettier the question, usually, the prettier the answer. Half assed question = half assed answers.

Comment: Do you need error checking in case the value at the position doesn't match?

Comment: Reason for the position is that allow only certain abbreviation word to be replaced, not all.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, what about this:

```
  public static void Main()
    {
        //var search = new Regex(@"spell\ correction", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        //var data = "this is a teit that i see that";

        List<Abbreviation> abbreviations = new List<Abbreviation>();
        abbreviations.Add(new Abbreviation() { Pos = 29, ShortName = "exp.", LongName = "expression" });
        abbreviations.Add(new Abbreviation() { Pos = 39, ShortName = "para.", LongName = "paragraph" });
        abbreviations.Add(new Abbreviation() { Pos = 54, ShortName = "ans.", LongName = "answer" });

        string test = "What is exp.? This is a test exp. in a para. contains ans. for a question";
        var offset = 0;
        abbreviations.ForEach(x => {

            if(test.Substring(x.Pos+ offset, x.ShortName.Length)==x.ShortName)
            {

                test = test.Remove(x.Pos + offset, x.ShortName.Length);
                test= test.Insert(x.Pos  + offset, x.LongName);
                offset += x.LongName.Length - x.ShortName.Length ;
            }

        }); // Need a LINQ expression
        Console.WriteLine(test);
    }
```

Comment: Don't use `.ForEach()`, just use a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Also. He did not specify that you need to account for the offset? Who you simply infered it. But he did not provide enough context to warrent it. Other than that, yet, would do the job. However, why simply not fix the initial issue with him having provided incorrect starting positions by just subtracting one from them also?
Lets say you program this for someone who knows what they are doing and they start counting at zero as  you are supposed to. This answer will screw up their code.

Comment: There is a service that returns the abbreviation list which includes the order in which words should be replaced, so reversing the list could avoid re-adjusting the positions.

Comment: My question was answered, thank you. Initially  I wanted to know any super efficient way of doing string manipulation using LINQ expression.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that if you replaced the abbreviation directly at the source, the position index of the next abbreviation you'd replace would be different from the one you declared at the beginning. So the way I see you'd need some helper variables to do it.

Also, your starting indexes were a bit off the mark.

**EDIT -** Replaced the LINQ `ForEach` by a regular `foreach` so that you won't have any conflicts using methods it doesn't support, like `String.IsNullOrEmpty()`

```
public class Abbreviation
{
    public int Pos { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public string LongName { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Abbreviation> abbreviations = new List<Abbreviation>();
        abbreviations.Add(new Abbreviation() { Pos = 29, ShortName = "exp.", LongName = "expression" });
        abbreviations.Add(new Abbreviation() { Pos = 39, ShortName = "para.", LongName = "paragraph" });
        abbreviations.Add(new Abbreviation() { Pos = 54, ShortName = "ans.", LongName = "answer" });

        string test = "What is exp.? This is a test exp. in a para. contains ans. for a question";

        string temp = "";
        int tempPos = 0;

        foreach (Abbreviation x in abbreviations)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(test) && (test.Length >= x.Pos + x.ShortName.Length) && test.Substring(x.Pos, x.ShortName.Length) == x.ShortName)
            {
                temp += test.Substring(tempPos, x.Pos) + x.LongName;
            }
            tempPos = x.Pos + x.ShortName.Length;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: If LINQ doesn't like the inner logic because of not supporting assembly methods like ones derived from `System.String`, we can always use a standard `foreach` instead.

Comment: You should just use a regular `foreach` loop.  `List.ForEach()` is always a bad idea

Comment: @maccettura yeah, it still isn't so clear for me either why LINQ can't access/doesn't reference other base assembly methods.